# Is it possible to read real live (Energy and Metal)data from Forex using python

Tags: python, yfinance, forex

I have python code which only  read real live data such currencies:

```
 df1 = yf.download(tickers = 'audusd' ,period ='1d', interval = '1h')  
 df2 = yf.download(tickers = 'usdjpy' ,period ='1d', interval = '1h')
```

but for gold (xauusd) and Natural Gas(xbrusd) and  others does not work:

```
df2 = yf.download(tickers = 'xauusd' ,period ='1d', interval = '1h')  does not work
df3 = yf.download(tickers = 'xbrusd' ,period ='1d', interval = '1h')
```

does not work

How I can read metal or energy or other from forex using yfinance library ?

Comment: Check https://finance.yahoo.com/, you'd probably need to find the abbreviation there

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip` to install `pandas-datareader`:

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

If I'm not mistaken, the correct tickers are `GC=F` for gold and `NG=F` for natural gas.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

df1 = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AUDUSD=X', period='1d', interval='1h')
df2 = pdr.get_data_yahoo('JPY=X', period='1d', interval='1h')
df3 = pdr.get_data_yahoo('GC=F', period='5d', interval='1h')
df4 = pdr.get_data_yahoo('NG=F', period='5d', interval='1h')
```

This does work when `period='5d'`, but doesn't work when `period='1d'`.

Here's a [quick start guide](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) on using `yfinance`.